# C++ code to execute a file every hour

Tags: c++, windows

I am currently faced with a problem where I need to execute a batch file every hour, can anyone provide a code spinet that will launch a designated file every hour e.g. myfile.bat ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the Task Scheduler service available for use, so I can't set tasks

Comment: I love to use [a spinet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spinet-q50-2822x829.jpg) to [execute files](http://petruccilibrary.org/wiki/Lessons_for_the_Harpsichord_or_Spinet_(Loeillet,_John)) sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your system environment you can easily accomplish this with a cronjob.

With a cronjob you can schedule it for any minute / hour / day / etc...

You can supply the cronjob to execute a path to a function where you can place a c++ exe to run the service you need.

For instance: I have a cronjob scheduled every hour to cURL a php function (this is a temporary workaround, normally i'd just run the php script) to send out emails on a user-preferece scheudle.

0 * * * *  curl http://mydomain.com/my_email_scheduler.php

the 5 digits preceeding my function call determine the schedule time

[minute] [hour] [day] [month] [day of week] command-line-to-be-executed

[Cron job guide](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

EDIT:: just noticed your comment that you don't have an available task scheduler.. I would then suggest to sleep a thread for every hour and execute a function upon waking.

Comment: Shoot -- just saw your comment that you don't have scheduler available... Can you sleep a thread to wake up every hour to execute a function?

Comment: Thanks, I have got hold of a cron port for Windows, called nncron

Comment: Oh good, so you'll be able to do this? I know windows has it's own native scheduler, I haven't used it though.. Something you might want to check out? Unless nncron works good then do the cronn!

Comment: security means you can't use the task scheduler, but cron is ok! Go figure?!

Comment: Yeah David -- who woulda thought... =P, Oh and +1 for realizing my answer mocks your original but mines accepted, sorry brotha.

Comment: I consider cron safer than Windows Task Scheduler, anything any with the name "Windows" in it, puts me of.

Comment: Anreas -- why do you say that?

Comment: @Daniel What are the risks of using task scheduler?

Comment: Its service based, where as I only want to run cron as a local user, do the maths..

Answer (score 4):

This isn't something you solve with an always on process. You should use a scheduled task for this. It solves all the problems for you.

If you absolutely had to do this in your own code the simplest solution is the `Sleep()` function. But I strongly advise against that approach.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this service available for use

Comment: what do you mean? Surely every windows machine runs scheduled tasks.

Comment: The environment has been heavily tweaked for security

Comment: Could you give an example of the Sleep() method in use in my case?

Comment: well you call Sleep passing 60*60*1000 milliseconds and the process will go to sleep for an hour. Each time it comes back  to life run your script and go to sleep again.

Answer (score 3):

[`CreateWaitableTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492.aspx), combined with any of the [wait functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using sleep would be to use [timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632592.aspx). <strike>It does mean you need to go through the process of creating a GUI though (probably not worth it at all if it's as simple as it sounds)</strike> <- My bad. One of the advantages of this is that you can make sure something is executed every half hour rather than every half hour + execution time for whatever it is.

Comment: No, I don't think you need to make a GUI in order to use timers.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, So you don't :) I have always used WM_TIMER messages rather than callback functions, and I'd completely forgotten about being able to set a callback at all. I'll correct it now.

Comment: @Mat You don't even need callback functions, you can create invisible windows if you so wish. This is a useful trick in many places - it allows non-GUI apps to do things that require a window handle.

Comment: @Mat: There are also [message-only windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#message_only) that I think you can use.

Comment: If you don't have a GUI, why set up a message queue?  Waitable timers work perfectly well in all types of applications (GUI, console, service, etc.)

Comment: @David Heffernan and @Andreas Rejbrand, by GUI I meant windows in general - invisible or not. In this case it would be easier to use callbacks.

Comment: yes it would but my point is that sometimes you really need window handles and you can have them without creating a GUI